# Implementation of Non-Generic Stack in Java

Tags: java

I'm starting out to work on DS in Java for the first time and thought that some inputs will get me going to more data structures. I implemented a stack which is non-generic. I followed some of the posts and realized that the top pointer should not be at -1. I know this is a very basic implementation (probably the worst). The LIFO part is working well. I am looking for suggestions on what are some ways to improve this code other than making this to be Generic Stack.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;


//******************************* Stack Demo Class **********//

class StackDemo{
  int stackarray[] , top;

  // Constructor

  StackDemo(int size){
    stackarray = new int[size+1];
    top = 0;
    System.out.println("The size of stack array is "+ (stackarray.length-1));
  }

  // *********************PUSH******************************//

  void push(int ele){
    if(top == stackarray.length - 1){
      System.out.println("Stack Overflow");
    }
    else{
      top++;
      stackarray[top] = ele;
    }
  } // Push Method


  // *********************POP******************************//

  int pop(){
    int lastElement = 0;
    if(top == 0){
      System.out.println("Stack is Underflow");
    }
    else{
      lastElement = stackarray[top];
      top--;
    }
    return lastElement;
  }  // Pop Method


  // *********************DISPLAY******************************//

  void display(){
    if(top == 0){
      System.out.println("Nothing to Display");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<=top ; i++){
      System.out.print(stackarray[i] +"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
  } // Display Method

}

// *****************************Main Class*******************//

public class Stacks{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    StackDemo sd = new StackDemo(10);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
      System.out.println("Enter your choice : \n 1.Push \n 2.Pop \n 3.Display \n 4.Exit");
      int choice = s.nextInt();
      switch(choice){
        case 1:
          System.out.println("Enter an Element to push");
          int pushElement = s.nextInt();
          sd.push(pushElement);
          break;
        case 2:
          int popElement = sd.pop();
          System.out.println("Popped Element is "+popElement);
          break;
        case 3:
          sd.display();
          break;
        case 4:
          System.exit(0);
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Enter valid choice");
      }  // Switch Closing
    } // While Closing
  } // Main method
} // Main class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code,

### Avoid Wild Imports

You import

```
import java.util.*;
```

but the only thing you use from the util package is Scanner,
so why not just

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Now it's obvious to anyone reading what you'll be using from util.

### Counting Starts at 0

```
stackarray = new int[size+1];
```

in your constructor, If I make a stack of size 10, I'm actually making one of size 11!

You're also accommodating for your +1 size in your constructor with

```
if(top == stackarray.length - 1){
   ...
}
```

if you just initialised your array as new int[size];

then this could look like

```
if(top == stackarray.length){
   ...
}
```

At the moment you're offsetting in 2 places, when in fact you don't need to do this anywhere! This is making the code more difficult for other people to follow.

In your display method

```
for (int i = 1; i<=top ; i++){
    ...
}
```

you can just start this at i = 0, starting at 1 is very unnatural.

this should be re-written like

```
for (int i = 0; i < top ; i++){
     ...
}
```

### Unusual Behaviour

right now, if I pop() an empty stack, it will return 0. This would be extremely unusual behaviour for an empty data structure. It wouldn't really be empty anymore would it?

```
  int pop(){
    int lastElement = 0;
    if(top == 0){
      System.out.println("Stack is Underflow");
    }
    else{
      lastElement = stackarray[top];
      top--;
    }
    return lastElement;
  }  // Pop Method
```

instead of printing "Stack is Underflow", why not throw a new EmptyStackException(msg). That's what it's for after all.

In your push method, you print a message if the stack is full. Again I would suggest throwing an appropriate exception here, or even better, you could ***resize*** the array to accommodate the new element. (This would be great practice for making an ArrayList implementation.)

### What's Missing?

Your stack is missing an **isEmpty()** or **empty()** method, this should just return true/false for if the stack is empty or not. This is extremely simple to implement so you shouldn't have any problems with this!

Your stack is missing a **peek()** method, this should show the next element, without removing it.

### Why Stop There?

Some other methods you might like to add for practice could be,

```
public boolean contains(int element) // if the lement is present in the stack

public int numberOf(int element) // occurrences of a given element

public int smallest() // the smallest element in the stack

public int largest()

public int totalSum()

public int average()
```

Hopefully this review was useful for you, keep it up!